# How can I optimize images and screenshots that I embed in my post?

Tags: discussion, support, faq

Uploading 1MB images or even 300KB images in a question or answer is often unnecessary/overkill and slows down page loads significantly especially when viewing on a mobile connection.
Similarly, really large dimensions are often pointless due to real-estate restrictions.

**How can I keep file sizes down or adjust the dimensions of the images to reasonable and sensible numbers?**

* <sup>Thanks to [coleopterist](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/247/coleopterist) over on http://anime.stackexchange.com for originally compiling this..</sup>

Answer (score 15):

If you don't have the wherewithal to *optimise* an image prior to upload, here are a few tips on doing so directly on SE.

After embedding an image to your post using the *upload* feature on the site, you should see an imgur URL similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSov.png (just using this as an example). This should result in a large image (190KB, a relatively reasonable size, but even this can be optimised further):

[image: ...and Another one!]

But this image can now be optimised even further simply by tweaking the URL being used. For example tweaking the URL to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSovt.png (note that the filename now has an **t** (for small) at the end) will result in an image of smaller size and dimension:

[image: ...and Another one!]

This file is only 3.5KB in size and also smaller in terms of dimensions.

If the dimensions are unsuitable add an **m** (for medium) or an **l** (for large) instead. This will result in the following images respectively:

1. [image: ...and Another one!] (9.7KB)
2. [image: ...and Another one!] (25.7KB)

Other options that also appear to work are:

- b (square crop?) [image: ...and Another one!] (38 KB)
- h (high quality original?) [image: ...and Another one!] (190KB)
- s (square cropped thumbnail?) [image: ...and Another one!] (15.6KB)

(I have no idea why the "square thumb" image is ~5KB larger than the "medium" one.)

---

If you'd nevertheless prefer viewers to be able to view your uploaded image in all its raw glory, simply link an optimised image to it by wrapping the code like this:

```
[![...my optimised image!][2]][1]
```

This will link the thumbnail to the original source file, like so:

[image: ...my optimised image!]

In other words, those wanting to view a higher resolution `[1]` can do so by simply clicking on the thumbnail `[2]`.

---

If these options are too complicated, just blindly add an *l* to the image filename in your post. This should display it in large dimensions and still load fast.

*I should also note that anime/cartoon images generally tend to be more optimisable than photographs, etc.*