# Button to insert <kbd></kbd> for users

Tags: support, questions

I come across a lot of posts which lack proper hotkey formatting: `any key`

And I change it to: <kbd>Any</kbd><kbd>Key</kbd>

It would save me 11 keystrokes per `<kbd></kbd>` if there was a button in the post editor toolbar.

Is there a way to add it? Or is it solely managed by SE?

[UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) has a unique wireframe-editor button, so there seem to be differences...

Comment: Any reason to not have this for users without moderator rights too?

Comment: I worry it could be abused by new users to highlight anything but shortcuts.

Comment: We already have that issue to some extent with the existing formatting options (mainly with backtics). We'll just have to edit these when needed. Users that stay around will eventually catch on (if not, we can just leave a comment pointing the the style guide meta).

Answer (score 16):

I have made a variant of the script [posted by CoDEmanX](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/390/599) with:

- Multi-char support
- A keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, if you think of a better available key, please comment)
- Optional key/mousebutton icons
- Support for reviewing/improving edits, answering own questions, etc.
- Undo support
- An icon
- Automatic extra space removal

Example of usage:

[image]

Tested on Firefox 59.0.2 and Chromium 65.0.3325.181.
Recommended to install with [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) for chrome users.

**[Greasyfork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/40087-kbd-formatting-button-for-stackexchange)**
**[Gist](https://gist.github.com/gandalf3/468e3704132a18dab7875341cca68571)**

---

Please forgive my less-than-polished js skills..

Comment: Nice additions gandalf! The problem with Chrome might be the sandboxing, since we inject the user script from another source (file:/// or localhost respectively)... The shortcut is not going to work for edits, 'cause it uses an ID: `$("#wmd-input").keydown(...)`. You might want to bind it to the class `.wmd-input` instead. There's a `}` too much at the end it seems.

Comment: Hm ok, that `}` is needed, the Firefox code highlighter just can't find the matching one of `main() {`? Very strange. The button works like a charm, but the shortcut doesn't. `Ctrl`+`E` places the cursor in the quick search field in Firefox, `Y` does nothing and `Z` is for undo (Z and Y are swapped on German keyboards, so I checked that too...). There's a feature missing from my script: the cursor placing after button use. With no text selected, it should insert a kbd-tag and place cursor inbetween, otherwise add tags and place cursor behind the last. Also focus() the textarea in both cases.

Comment: Ok, I fixed some problems and optimized the embedded icon, works for me in Firefox. Hotkey is a bit problematic it seems, doesn't work in some cases. Back-ported my cursor placement. http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/486617

Comment: Mystery solved: the deprecated `.live()` worked for the hotkey, but `.on()` didn't - 'cause it needs to be used on `document` and the elements we are interested in are given as second parameter as filter! Works like charm!

Comment: Brilliant :) I didn't do anything, but the hotkey didn't give me any trouble.. On my FF `Ctrl E` does nothing, however chrome puts it in the url bar, so I guess that's a no go either way. It would be nice to have a key a bit closer to `left Ctrl`, but it doesn't look like there is one free. Is it worth breaking the theme of using `Ctrl` to use `Alt`+nearby-sensible-letter or something instead?

Comment: I added extra space removal, so now extra spaces are removed automatically. I also scaled down the icon to 20px so it fits better, but as a result un-optimized it again :/ (idk how to optimize it). I tried to get the button `li` to go after the image  button (it seems like the right category to me) by replacing `appendTo` with `insertAfter("#wmd-image-button")`, but it still goes at the end??

Comment: Wow, this is really nice. Great job guys. Can we agree on one final version. @gandalf3 Would recommend uploading to userscripts.org so it can be 1 click installation.

Comment: @iKlsR Okay. Still not quite done yet, still some kinks imo (plus it's currently not working on chrome, looking at that now). Working again, jquery was used before it was loaded..

Comment: Really didn't see the need for a dependency tho.

Comment: For me, Ctrl+Y is fine, 'cause it's the closest key to Left Ctrl on my German keyboard ;) Ctrl+E is used by both browsers, so better not overwrite default behavior. You can optimize PNGs using https://tinypng.com/, which uses http://pngquant.org/. `insertAfter` doesn't work, 'cause every button has an offset (`left: 25px` * n, where n is the index). To insert another button, you would have to get the previous offset and add 25px to your and all subsequent buttons. @iKlsR: It did not work on Chrome apparantly, might be caused by its sandboxing / same-origin-policy. It does in Firefox however.

Comment: I made [an adaptation](https://gist.github.com/L0Lock/e457e163bd50b5e08f91965fced9eb2c) of it for [Blender Community](https://blender.community/#), just the keyboard shortcut part.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks iKlsR, I created a Greasemonkey script based on your code, which inserts a new button automatically:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Add <kbd> Button to StackExchange Toolbar
// @namespace   http://blender.org
// @include     *.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var toolbar;
function toolbar_wait() {
    toolbar = document.getElementById('wmd-button-row');
    if (toolbar == null) {
        window.setTimeout(toolbar_wait, 500);
    } else {
        toolbar_add();
    }
}
toolbar_wait();

function insert_kbd()
{
    var txta = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
    if (txta.selectionStart == null) return;
    var chars = txta.value.split("");
    chars.splice(txta.selectionStart, 0, '<kbd>');
    chars.splice(txta.selectionEnd + 1, 0, '</kbd>');
    txta.value = chars.join("");
    toolbar_update();
}

function toolbar_add() {

    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    style.innerHTML = '#wmd-kbd-button:hover {background-color: #deedff;}';
    document.body.appendChild(style);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.onclick = insert_kbd;
    li.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 9pt; left: 400px;');
    li.setAttribute('title', 'Keyboard Shortcut <kbd>')
    li.setAttribute('id', 'wmd-kbd-button')
    toolbar.appendChild(li);
    li.className = 'wmd-button';

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = 'kbd';
    span.setAttribute('style', 'background-image:none;');
    li.appendChild(span);
}

function toolbar_update() {

    var element = document.getElementById('wmd-input');

    var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


    keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                   "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                    true, // bubbles
                    true, // cancelable
                    window, // viewArg: should be window
                    false, // ctrlKeyArg
                    false, // altKeyArg
                    false, // shiftKeyArg
                    false, // metaKeyArg
                    17, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
    );
    element.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);

}
```

Install: https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/486617

I added a hack to simulate a keydown event (ctrl) to make the live markdown preview update. Tested and working in Firefox 28.

Comment: Installed via Tampermonkey and working on latest version of chrome as well. Really nice. Thanks. I couldn't figure how to get the live update so I just opted to have it trigger with other user input after. ;)

Comment: I initially had it binded to `wmd-input` too but changed it as I thought since I was using a bookmarklet it could be useful elsewhere as well.

Comment: `<kbd>` isn't supported in comment anyway, I use `backticks` instead. Thanks for testing! Now, should I accept my own answer or yours?

Comment: Tested on Chrome OS X & it works GREAT if I'm creating an answer, but the kbd button is not there if I try to edit an existing answer.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Yours will do. I mean't elsewhere, not comments, we all use backticks ;). I need some sleep.

Comment: Alright! I updated the script to use jQuery and made it work that it also injects the button if you edit posts. Hope it still works for everyone. I couldn't find a jQuery-way of updating the markdown preview, so left that untouched for now and created a question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460904/jquery-replacement-for-dispatchevent-keydown-how-to-get-trigger-working

Answer (score 5):

Such a feature is not available in the formatting toolbar, you have to do it manually. I've often wanted the same feature as [it is encouraged](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/250/12) that posts be formatted correctly, [especially input](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/12).

My javascript is really, really rusty but I managed to throw something together that should save a bit of time *(a few seconds at least ;)* when doing this.

## Install

1. Drag this line of code to your bookmarks bar, [raw](https://bpaste.net/raw/021c2f8439e8). (only tested on chrome and firefox).

   ```
   javascript:(function(){var txta = document.activeElement; if (txta.selectionStart == undefined) return; var chars = txta.value.split(""); chars.splice(txta.selectionStart, 0, '<kbd>'); chars.splice(txta.selectionEnd + 1, 0, '</kbd>'); txta.value = chars.join("");})()
   ```
2. You can then rename the newly created bookmark to something useful.

## Usage

Select the text to be wrapped in the textarea and click the bookmark.

Comment: Someone who has a few minutes to spare could convert this into a userscript and have it fit nicely in the formatting toolbar methinks.

Comment: Never made user scripts before, but I'll give it a go :)

Comment: Super awesome! One question: on my OS X with Chrome, for some reason the formatting does not display in the formatting preview until I press some other key in the editing window. I'm not complaining, just wondering if this is a known issue?

Comment: Can we have a favicon for it too?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII Not really an issue per se, the input field needs some sort of trigger to update the `kbd` preview. CoDEmanX's script below has a little hack for getting around this and is much better.

Answer (score 1):

### Autohotkey

Since I'm using Autohotkey, I wrote myself a script. Still not tested thoroughly... I'm just using the Unicode symbols, rather than specifying them by Unicode codepoints, so you need to save the script as *UTF-8 with BOM*, and use Authotokey version supporting UTF-8. As AHK works only on Windows, I didn't include any Mac specific keys. Also I chose glyphs by prioritizing readability rather than being rigorous on their meaning...

There are 3 complex glyphs for *Lock* keys produced with *MathJax* - not sure if everyone will see them properly:

<kbd>$\fbox{A}$ CAPS LOCK</kbd> <kbd>$\fbox{1}$ Num Lock</kbd> <kbd>$\rlap{\fbox{ ⬇ }} \_\;$ Scroll Lock</kbd>

Desired result:

[image]

Also I don't put mouse hints inside `<kbd>`, as those aren't keys, but that might be pedantic reasoning; and I don't use images because it would be harder to do and I have mixed feelings about embedding images so aggressively. The script will also add a 3-word description to a mouse indicator:

- `lmb;;` $\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button*
- `mmb;;` $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}0\color{#888}{█}$ *middle mouse button*
- `mwu;;` $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬆\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel up*
- `mwd;;` $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down*
- `rmb;;` $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right mouse button*

Usage:

- for mouse indicators type the strings visible above
- for keys that produce a visible glyph, type `kb` then the key (with no modifiers), then two semicolons `;;` e.g. `kb;;;` for <kbd>;</kbd> or `kbe;;` for <kbd>E</kbd>
- for numpad keys type `numpad`, then as above, e.g. `numpad4;;` for <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>
- `kbf1;;` to `kbf12;;` for <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys
- the rest of special keys by name without `kb` prefix:

`ctrl;;`<kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd>
;
`alt;;`<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>
;
`shift;;`<kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>
;
`win;;`<kbd>❖ Win</kbd>
;
`menu;;`<kbd>☰ Menu</kbd>
;
`enter;;`<kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>
;
`numpadenter;;`<kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd>
;
`tab;;`<kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>
;
`del;;`<kbd>⌦ Del</kbd>
;
`ins;;`<kbd>⎀ Ins</kbd>
;
`home;;`<kbd>|⬅ Home</kbd>
;
`end;;`<kbd>➡| End</kbd>
;
`backsp;;`<kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd>
;
`space;;`<kbd>␣ Spacebar</kbd>
;
`pgup;;`<kbd>⬆ Page Up</kbd>
;
`pgdn;;`<kbd>⬇ Page Down</kbd>
;
`prtscr;;`<kbd>⎙ Prt Scr</kbd>
;
`capslock;;`<kbd>$\fbox{A}$ CAPS LOCK</kbd>
;
`scrolllock;;`<kbd>$\rlap{\fbox{ ⬇ }} \_\;$ Scroll Lock</kbd>
;
`numlock;;`<kbd>$\fbox{1}$ Num Lock</kbd>
;
`up;;`<kbd>⬆ Up</kbd>
;
`left;;`<kbd>⬅ Left</kbd>
;
`right;;`<kbd>➡ Right</kbd>
;
`down;;`<kbd>⬇ Down</kbd>

### AHK script

Consider adding `#if WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ahk_exe firefox.exe")` as first line so it works only in Firefox.

```
#Hotstring EndChars . `n `t
#Hotstring NoMouse
#Hotstring c r *
; c - case sensitive
; r - send raw
; * - ending character not required

::lmb;;::$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button*
::mmb;;::$\color{#888}{█}\color{green}0\color{#888}{█}$ *middle mouse button*
::mwu;;::$\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬆\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel up* 
::mwd;;::$\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down* 
::rmb;;::$\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right mouse button*

::ctrl;;::<kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd>
::alt;;::<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>
::shift;;::<kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>
::win;;::<kbd>❖ Win</kbd>
::menu;;::<kbd>☰ Menu</kbd>
::enter;;::<kbd>↩ Enter</kbd>
::tab;;::<kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>
::del;;::<kbd>⌦ Del</kbd>
::ins;;::<kbd>⎀ Ins</kbd>
::home;;::<kbd>|⬅ Home</kbd>
::end;;::<kbd>➡| End</kbd>
::backsp;;::<kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd>
::space;;::<kbd>␣ Spacebar</kbd>
::pgup;;::<kbd>⬆ Page Up</kbd>
::pgdn;;::<kbd>⬇ Page Down</kbd>
::prtscr;;::<kbd>⎙ Prt Scr</kbd>
::capslock;;::<kbd>$\fbox{A}$ CAPS LOCK</kbd>
::scrolllock;;::<kbd>$\rlap{\fbox{ ⬇ }} \_\;$ Scroll Lock</kbd> ; <kbd>$\fbox{↕}$ Scroll Lock</kbd>
::numlock;;::<kbd>$\fbox{1}$ Num Lock</kbd>

::numpad0;;::<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>
::numpad1;;::<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>
::numpad2;;::<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd>
::numpad3;;::<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>
::numpad4;;::<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>
::numpad5;;::<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>
::numpad6;;::<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>
::numpad7;;::<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>
::numpad8;;::<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd>
::numpad9;;::<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd>
::numpad/;;::<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>
::numpad*;;::<kbd>Numpad *</kbd>
::numpad-;;::<kbd>Numpad -</kbd>
::numpad+;;::<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>
::numpadenter;;::<kbd>Numpad Enter</kbd>
::numpad.;;::<kbd>Numpad .</kbd>

::up;;::<kbd>⬆ Up</kbd>
::left;;::<kbd>⬅ Left</kbd>
::right;;::<kbd>➡ Right</kbd>
::down;;::<kbd>⬇ Down</kbd>

::kbf1;;::<kbd>F1</kbd>
::kbf2;;::<kbd>F2</kbd>
::kbf3;;::<kbd>F3</kbd>
::kbf4;;::<kbd>F4</kbd>
::kbf5;;::<kbd>F5</kbd>
::kbf6;;::<kbd>F6</kbd>
::kbf7;;::<kbd>F7</kbd>
::kbf8;;::<kbd>F8</kbd>
::kbf9;;::<kbd>F9</kbd>
::kbf10;;::<kbd>F10</kbd>
::kbf11;;::<kbd>F11</kbd>
::kbf12;;::<kbd>F12</kbd>
::kb``;;::<kbd>`</kbd>
::kb1;;::<kbd>1</kbd>
::kb2;;::<kbd>2</kbd>
::kb3;;::<kbd>3</kbd>
::kb4;;::<kbd>4</kbd>
::kb5;;::<kbd>5</kbd>
::kb6;;::<kbd>6</kbd>
::kb7;;::<kbd>7</kbd>
::kb8;;::<kbd>8</kbd>
::kb9;;::<kbd>9</kbd>
::kb0;;::<kbd>0</kbd>
::kb-;;::<kbd>-</kbd>
::kb=;;::<kbd>=</kbd>
::kb[;;::<kbd>[</kbd>
::kb];;::<kbd>]</kbd>
::kb;;;::<kbd>;</kbd>
::kb';;::<kbd>'</kbd>
::kb\;;::<kbd>\</kbd>
::kb,;;::<kbd>,</kbd>
::kb.;;::<kbd>.</kbd>
::kb/;;::<kbd>/</kbd>

::kbq;;::<kbd>Q</kbd>
::kbw;;::<kbd>W</kbd>
::kbe;;::<kbd>E</kbd>
::kbr;;::<kbd>R</kbd>
::kbt;;::<kbd>T</kbd>
::kby;;::<kbd>Y</kbd>
::kbu;;::<kbd>U</kbd>
::kbi;;::<kbd>``I``</kbd>
::kbo;;::<kbd>O</kbd>
::kbp;;::<kbd>P</kbd>
::kba;;::<kbd>A</kbd>
::kbs;;::<kbd>S</kbd>
::kbd;;::<kbd>D</kbd>
::kbf;;::<kbd>F</kbd>
::kbg;;::<kbd>G</kbd>
::kbh;;::<kbd>H</kbd>
::kbj;;::<kbd>J</kbd>
::kbk;;::<kbd>K</kbd>
::kbl;;::<kbd>L</kbd>
::kbz;;::<kbd>Z</kbd>
::kbx;;::<kbd>X</kbd>
::kbc;;::<kbd>C</kbd>
::kbv;;::<kbd>V</kbd>
::kbb;;::<kbd>B</kbd>
::kbn;;::<kbd>N</kbd>
::kbm;;::<kbd>M</kbd>
```