# How to add the boxes around the keyboard buttons?

Tags: support, questions, answers, formatting

When I posted an answer for someones question:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/16530/revisions

It got edited and these key box's were added.
They look nifty, but because I'm new, I don't know how to add them.

Could someone clarify please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, your original post was a bit untidy and it was formatted properly by other users. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: I agree whole-heatedly that I was sloppy. If you look in the areas where I had put key notations (ex. 'N') they were replaced by some sort of icon in the edit. how does one use those icons to avoid future 'mistakes'?

Comment: And with my most recent answer to my own question. How did you do that? Pretty cool. Maybe i just need a course on formatting in this site.

Comment: That was done using markdown, when writing a post, look at the top of the edit field to the right and you will see a help button (a gold question mark). See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style. You can also drop by our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) and ask for assistance, you will get used to the site in no time. :)

Comment: Also here's a quick and basic guide to using markdown and html within SE posts: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. The formatting in question is `<kbd>key</kbd>`. If you get tired of typing `<kbd>`, there is a userscript which adds a button to insert them automatically: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/388/599

Comment: cool. thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are simply [kbd tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd), defined in the html spec, and styled as such on SE.

Here is an example usage:

> When you really messed up, press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is how the sage advice looks in code view:
`When you really messed up, press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`.

For more detail on how to format the kbd tags see [this answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/527/2217).

There are also user created [scripts](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/2217) to make adding the `<kbd>` tags easier.

Answer (score 2):

It's sooo annoying to type those kbd tags though. If one is on Windows, one can use a simple [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
#NoEnv 
SendMode Input
#K::
a := Clipboard
send ^c
ClipWait
sleep 100
StringReplace, Clipboard, Clipboard, + , %A_Space%</kbd> + <kbd>%A_Space%, ReplaceAll
StringReplace, Clipboard, Clipboard, -> , %A_Space%</kbd> -> <kbd>%A_Space%, ReplaceAll
StringUpper, Clipboard, Clipboard, T
Clipboard = <kbd>%A_Space%%Clipboard%%A_Space%</kbd>
sleep 100
Send ^v
sleep 200
Clipboard := a
return
```

So if that AHK script(text file with .ahk exxtension) is in `shell:startup`(one could copy-paste that to Windows Run menu( <kbd>Winlogo</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd> )) folder and starts with Windows, one can simply select some text like "a->ctrl+b" and hit  <kbd>Winlogo</kbd>  +  <kbd>K</kbd>  to get " <kbd>A</kbd>  ->  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd> "

AHK needs to be installed.