# What case should letters inside <kbd> tags be?

Tags: discussion, formatting

What case should letters inside `<kbd>` tags be?

e.g.

- <kbd>⎈ ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>⎈ CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

Any there any advantages or disadvantages to different styles? Should we try to maintain a consistent style across the site, in keeping with the wiki nature of SE?

Comment: I am not sure how important this is in the grand scheme of things (actually I think it really isn't) but I am a detail-oriented freak :).  So I think if everybody read this and followed it would be great!

Comment: A trivial problem at most, I don't see many people using all caps and having the first letter capitalized is optional, either way, it's optional at most. I can also say that most of the time, these are in the second form that you showed.

Comment: @iKlsR Most of the time.. But more than once I have found myself editing posts with lower case single key shortcuts, and I decided to write a meta to make sure I was doing the right thing by capitalizing them.

Answer (score 12):

I capitalize the one letter keys, and <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>. I specify the NumPad as such:

> Press <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> to switch to front view.

The modifiers, I capitalize just the first letter such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>. However I find that a lowercase <kbd>space</kbd> looks better.

Comment: This how I personally do it, and it seems to be consistent with other sources as well.

Answer (score 6):

I vote for <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. This is the way it appears on the keyboard (at least on my keyboard), and as the formatting seems to be designed to represent a physical key, it might as well have the same case as a key.

I don't see any reason to use lower case instead of upper case. The only case I can think of is to differentiate between shortcuts using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and those not using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>. However, I think just using `<kbd>&#8679; Shift</kbd>` is a lot clearer, see the following example:

- Using case to indicate the usage of <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>:

  > Press <kbd>g</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd>
- Using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> to indicate the usage of <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>:

  > Press <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

As far as maintaining this consistently across site, I think it would be nice if posts were styled consistently, but I'm not sure how realistic of a goal that is.

Comment: On many windows keyboards it is actually not displayed that way. The windows key defaults to the windows start menu, and the Control key just has Ctrl on it.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics I'm not sure what you mean by "windows keyboard", but granted, this probably does vary widely between different keyboards. For instance, my keyboard does have a ⎈ on the Ctrl key. And as the other modifier keys commonly seem to have their own "icon", I figured it would be consistent to include it with Ctrl too. I'm not sure I see the relevance of your second point though. Who said anything about the windows/OS logo key?

Comment: Sorry about that, the graphic on the Ctrl key is a simplified windows symbol.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics Hm.. Not for me, that might be another problem. It should be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#mediaviewer/File:ISOIEC-9995-7-026--ISO-7000-2028--Symbol-for-Control.svg), which is done in the above post with the Unicode character `&#9096;`.

Comment: Very interesting! I looked up control key on the web ( https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=941&q=ctrl+key&oq=Ctrl+&gs_l=img.3.1.0l10.1845.5049.0.6988.5.5.0.0.0.0.122.576.0j5.5.0....0...1ac.1.58.img..0.5.575.fSGWiqLj-TA#imgdii=_ ), I can not find one with the graphic. Is your keyboard moderately new? EDIT: Just found one ( http://xahlee.info/kbd/i2/Microsoft_keyboard_control_windows_alt_keys.jpg ). Since it seems to be so obscure, do you think it is necessary?

Comment: I agree 100% with the layout you suggested for the Shift key, BTW.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics Huh, that's interesting indeed! It's not really very new, no.  Just your average somewhat-old-but-not-really-ancient microsoft keyboard. Here's a [picture](http://xahlee.info/kbd/i2/Microsoft_keyboard_control_windows_alt_keys.jpg) of a similar one (doesn't look like mine, but the Ctrl key is the same)

Comment: I am having a very hard time finding examples using the graphic. It seems to have been discontinued. Let me do some research . . .

Comment: It almost looks like the symbol is a replacement for the plain-text version: "Also, there is a standardized keyboard symbol (to be used when Latin lettering is not preferred) . . ." See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key  Notice that all of their abbreviations are Ctrl + _

Answer (score 4):

To create an *appearance* of consistency, someone could add a little css rule for `<kbd>`.

```
kbd {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

With `text-transform: capitalize`, regardless of the actual capitalization, the first letter of each word would always *display* capitalized. Therefore either <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> would always *appear* as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Unfortunately `capitalize` would not produce complete uniformity since only the first letter of each word is transformed. Completely capitalize words, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> would remain entirely capitalize.