# kbd shortcuts and unwillingness to comply

Tags: discussion

Related to comments on [How to move points proportionally to keep edge flow good?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115133/how-to-move-points-proportionally-to-keep-edge-flow-good?noredirect=1#comment201881_115136) , which are getting out of hand and inappropriate to where they're occurring.

I like helping people.  However, I am only willing to go to so much effort to help people.  I don't go to effort to do things that I think are a waste of time unless I'm getting paid, right?

I like to provide information that people would find useful, including keyboard shortcuts for Blender operations I reference.  I am not going to use  tags because it's tedious and I don't see any point to it.  So my question is, what would the BSE community prefer?

1) I walk away and stop answering questions.

2) I continue to answer questions but provide no keyboard shortcuts.

3) I provide whatever keyboard shortcuts are convenient for me and people that care about keyboard shortcuts can edit my posts as they wish.

To me, 3) seems like the best option for people using BSE.

Obviously there are going to be differences of opinion on this, I'm looking for something approaching community consensus, which I'll respect.

Comment: In my opinion you're approaching this too pedantically. Markup is for visual convinience to read and understand what's written. For example in original text of your linked answer shortcuts can be misinterpreted as description for *that* question (A, B, C as designating triangle and A as shortcut etc). If you are really bad with putting those markups inline then e.g. write them all caps with pluses in between, like SHIFT+C.

Comment: Thanks @MrZak , that is acceptable to me, and I'll do that in the future.

Comment: Also look here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style and here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users maybe this could be less tedious for you.

Comment: As someone who absolutely overuses `<kbd>` tags wherever possible, I would hate to type them manually. cgslav already linked it, but I can't emphasize enough how useful I find the [kbd insertion userscript](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/599).  (disclaimer: I helped write it, so I *may* be biased)

Answer (score 7):

First off the comments you linked to are not inappropriate or out of hand. A user asked you to make your answer better by adding `<kbd>`. Suggesting improvements is one of the designed uses of comments.

Now on to your problem.
Unless you are planing on writing answers that just names the tool and not how to get to it; then I think you will find the `<kbd>` is much quicker.

Lets take the "Show Hidden" tool as an example. (I'm sure you know this tool, and use it all the time. However if you do not know how to get to it (and I always assume someone reading my answers will not) then you will have to show them:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

Or

> From the 3D view header *Mesh* > *Show/Hide* > *Show Hidden*

Which would you prefer? (I do both)

To get the best benefit out of your answers you should have the shortcuts wrapped in `<kbd>` tags. We even have something of a [style guide](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/2217) for them.
It really is not that much work. I have typed `<kbd>` 1,830 times in my posts (and that is just on BSE).  It's something that takes very little extra effort and almost no extra time, yet makes the post much better.
Just do it.

---

If all that did not convince you, then yes your option three is the least bad.

Comment: You don't use the userscript? :(

Answer (score 4):

> I walk away and stop answering questions.

That would be an act of a little kid. Looking at the comment thread you were far from harassed, people just gave you feedback that kbd shortcuts are better readable and would appreciate you for formatting them.

No one forces you to do anything, format your answers however you like. The best answer gets the upvotes and I think you now know what such answer looks like. It has pictures, gifs, is well worded, structured into paragraphs and among other things has formatted shortcuts.

Putting time into this is not a waste

- you save a fellow user's time if your answer doesn't require formatting.
- you make better answers that gets you more points and you can brag about them when getting work from clients or when job hunting.

Basically the more effort you put into building this site the more it's users will like you and the better public image you will get. You can even get one level fancier with shortcuts to reach god tier:

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>

If you don't care about any of this, that's fine, but I wouldn't count on other people editing your answers to look better when they know you are purposely making them that way.

---

That said formatting them could be easier, true. Could require less key strokes like `> quote`, `**bold**`, `*italic*`, `[link](http://)`, etc. Something similar like this `{Ctrl}+{C}` or this `<Ctrl>+<V>`..

There is this: [Button to insert <kbd></kbd> for users](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users/), requires browser extension.

---

> My walking away would solve people's frustration when keyboard tags are not used (...) It's not a threat, it's an offer. And you don't speak for everyone on the site.(...) It is clearly something that matters to some people.

You are right that I can only speak for myself. But consider this:

This site is a competition. It's a hunt for points. Regular users on this site want those points - they give benefits (more rights on this site and the bragging I mentioned when looking for work or job). It's the currency here, people give bounties in them.

Something that can be improved is an opportunity to post a competing content. Anyone being frustrated by your answers would be stupid, trust me. If there is someone like that, do not pay attention to them, ignore them, their frustration is their problem and you don't have to solve it by walking away or providing no shortcuts, you don't owe them that.

People commenting (to increase readability of posts) are like people suggesting improvements to a competitor. If you reject those suggestions, it's tedious and not an option for you and the suggested benefits are not worth the effort - they can:

- post competing answer (opportunity to get points)
- edit yours

If there wasn't the 1st option and voting on answers, I would understand why someone might get frustrated - it would be like someone not conforming to standards of wiki editing for example. But this site is different. There is reward and there is opportunity to compete. Would you be frustrated if your competition did something you think can be done better?

Because of this, it's not your fault if there is someone frustrated with your answer. Some answer is always better than no answer and they can post theirs anytime if they think yours is low quality.

You might even find some benefactor altruistic people here that will edit the shortcuts for you without any frustration of doing work for you to help your answers be more readable and probably get more points. Anyone else can post competing answer.

Comment: "That would be an act of a little kid."  Nobody has a responsibility to participate in Stack Exchange.  Don't escalate.  I'm offering people options.

Comment: @Nathan The option of you walking away does solve *what* exactly? Nobody forces you to do anything as far as I am aware.

Comment: My walking away would solve people's frustration when keyboard tags are not used, because there would be fewer messages without appropriate tags.  I mean, "solve" is kind of saying it too strongly.  I don't get it, was that not clear?

Comment: @Nathan I think you miss-interpret this - no one is frustrated with you, I am not and it would be so sad if anyone else was. There is no reason for it, you did nothing wrong. Walking away would only hurt this site, not help anyone, that's why I called it act of a little kid - solves nothing and it's a threat. Sure you do get constructive feedback in this community, people suggest what you could improve - it's all in a friendly manner and intend, supported by arguments. This is healthy, helps you grow, it helps me grow, I learned so much from others and their suggestions.

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  It's not a threat, it's an offer.  And you don't speak for everyone on the site.  I'm glad you're not frustrated.  Don't think that because you aren't, no one else is.  It is clearly something that matters to some people.  It is not something I intend on doing.  When you're in a situation like that, offering to walk away is the adult thing to do, not the childish thing.

Comment: @Nathan I too care about how this site looks, true, it matters to me. But if you decide to not listen to the suggestion, that is fine, then people should respect your decision. I would not be mad or frustrated with you, why would I, you don't work for me or anyone else here. I would respect your decision to neglect formatting shortcuts and would leave your answer as is. I would give my upvote to the better answer or submit a competing answer that is better formatted. No one would like to become your personal assistant to improve your posts, I hope you can see that.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad that you respect that.  It's important to me and I appreciate it.  I don't expect anyone to become my personal assistant to improve my posts, but they can feel free to do so if that's something important to them.  Why would I want them to?  I would have to think that keyboard formatting was important to want people to do that for me.