# How do I hilight words in grey such as Blender hot keys?

Tags: support, editing

I've searched right through the markup help and can't find any mention anywhere of what hotkey or incantation to use to create the grey hilighting (with or without the surrounding box outline) when writing an answer to a question, e.g: CTRL + X with the 'CTRL and 'X' hilighted. Any clues please? - Just found mention of the 'kbd' tag, but how do you use it? Surely you don't have to type in the full HTML formatting every time you want to hilight a letter?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find that by searching.

Comment: @JohnEason there are also some userscripts around SE, such as [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users) and [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) for example that add kbd tags for you.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks. I'll have a look!