# Should information on how to use <kbd> be taught to new users?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that many edits by moderators are to change keystrokes like CTRL + A to the proper <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> format.

Should information on how to properly use key command formatting be included i.e. on the tour page, or even when trying to post your first question?

I know it took me a very long time to figure out how to correctly format key commands, and I think it would take a lot of load off of the moderators if we could educate new users right from the get go.

Comment: Using `kbd` is optional even tho it's nicer to read. Generally speaking, edits should be substantial as opposed to small visual changes. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241/micro-editing-does-everything-need-to-be-perfect. There is a small header above the editing area with helpful tooltips and a help panel. A one minute glance at the help center should get anyone up to scratch with se if they are interested.

Comment: From personal experience, I could not find out how to properly format key commands, and every single time I posted a question or answer, it would be edited and the <kbd> tags inserted in the correct places, even if no other edits were made. This was both frustrating, and made me less likely to post anything that required you to press a button. I also could not locate the information on the web for several weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important thing is we get clear & helpful answers, having to know too many details *(and being an expert on SE markup)* before you begin can also be off-putting.

SHortcuts formatted as `Ctrl+C` are clear, so any answers without `<kbd>` markup are still easily understandable.

So prefer not to be picky about this matter, popular answers from less experienced editors will likely be edited to improve the formatting later on anyway.

Comment: Good points. Between this and what @iKlsR said, I think that I understand why we shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to think **no**.

Most users probably come here just to ask a quick question, and might not ever really plan on coming back regularly when they first join. There are enough active users here to edit and add `<kbd>` formatting to  keyboard shortcuts.

For new users who want to learn/regularly be active, they will figure it out. This information is readily available in the [help pages](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), which are linked in the Ask a question page:

[image]

Even if such places are left undiscovered, if active users edit keyboard shortcuts to add kbd formating, a curious user only needs to click *edit* to see the raw markdown and discover how it was accomplished.

And if all else fails, they can always ask ;)

**TL;DR:** We shouldn't force irrelevant and unneeded knowledge users don't want or necessarily need to know before they can use the site. Users who do want to know will find out easily enough on their own.

Comment: More excellent points! However, could the <kbd> tag be included on the menu to the right, as how to write key commands? It wouldn't really clutter it, and it would make things a lot easier to figure out. Still, I get all of you guy's points, and maybe it is better just to let them figure it out themselves. It was extremely frustrating on my part, I know that . . .

Comment: I couldn't agree more, but that's a feature request for stackexchange. Feel free to ask on the [global meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) ;). BTW, in case you haven't already found it, iKlsR, CoDEmanX, and I wrote a [userscript](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/388/599) a while ago which adds a kbd button to the toolbar.

Comment: Sweet! That will save a lot of typing!

Comment: I put it on the global meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244032/should-how-to-use-kbd-tags-be-included-in-the-how-to-format-list should I delete this question?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics No need to, it's relevant here.

Comment: Big difference between forcing it on people and offering the information. I agree that nagging is bad. Educating first time posters regarding the essentials in an entertaining way however is good. I personally miss a <LMB> <MMB> and <RMB> tag. "If they're interested, they will find it" is definitely not what I perceive as 'offering information' though

Comment: @Haunt_House [`<kbd>` is part of html](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866#section-5.7), I doubt SE wants to add custom tags :P No reason we can't put RMB MMB and LMB in `<kbd>` tags, see for example how the [`<kbd>` button script](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/388/599) does it.

Comment: @gandalf3 You can persuade almost anyone if you are persistent and elegant and dedicated. I just have more relevant fights to do. I'd still like a cute little mouse with a highlighted button though.

Comment: @Haunt_House That's what the kbd script inserts (using an image), see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24589/599) for e.g.