# Making Mouse Icons

Tags: support

How do you make the icons like in David's bio?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>

```
 <kbd>![RMB][RMB] RMB</kbd>

  [RMB]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPwD4.png (Right Mouse Button)
```

The mouse icon is simply an image, embedded via markdown syntax just like any other image.

I and some other users have [written a userscript](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/599) which allows these and other `<kbd>` buttons to be inserted with a single keyboard shortcut.

---

The links for each icon are as follows:

<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPwD4.png`

<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwrAW.png`

<kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/OASpJ.png`

<kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1vyT.png`

The icons originate from the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Meta:Guides/Templates#Mouse_hotkeys), but it was decided during the development of the userscript to host them on imgur in case the wiki versions changed.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! wouldn't I of been better to answer this one... :)

Comment: @David heh.. :P