# How to post gifs on this site?

Tags: support

Most replies to my comments have "gif" images. How do I put them in my posts? Adding a new image doesn't work.

Also, this will help with asking questions because I always need to show examples.

Comment: This belongs to meta  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Depending on your browser pasting an image from clipboard doesn't work (Ctrl-V) In this case you need to store the image as a file and upload it.

Comment: I got an error: 'For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.'

Comment: LICEcap does not have this issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your gif is under 2MB (*IIRC*), you can upload it the normal way when asking or answering a question, by clicking on the image icon, drag and drop, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Due to [link rot hosting images on external sites is no longer recommended](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/bse-has-a-external-image-problem) on Blender Stack exchange.

See the [section about reducing Gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964#964) sizes on tips to get your captures under 2Mb so they can be hosted on *i.stack.imgur*.

If it's larger, then you will need to use another hosting service, e.g. [gfycat][1] (it's free, no registration required, and the images stay around "forever").

Once you have uploaded your image to gfycat (or the host of your choosing), get the link to it. If you are using gfycat, press the link icon and copy the url for "gif":

[image]

Then add it to your post with the following markdown:

```
![image description](http://giant.gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth.gif)
```

where `http://giant.gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth.gif` is the link to your gif, and `image description` is a description (alt text) of your gif.

Since gfycat encodes your gif as a video as well, I also like to include a link to the html 5 version. You can make it so the gif is in the link, so that clicking on the image will go to the gfycat page with the html5 video of your gif.
To do this, simply wrap the image link in another link:

```
[![a bunch of bouncing spheres](http://giant.gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth.gif)](http://gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth)
```

When rendered, it looks like this:

[a bunch of bouncing spheres http://giant.gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth.gif](http://gfycat.com/WiltedIdealCottonmouth)

For more information, see the [markdown formatting guides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images).

Comment: Doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Dr.jacky It seems gfycat doesn't give out links to actual `gif` files anymore, but you can still get a gif by appending `.gif` to the url manually. It does seem to watermark it, however.

Comment: For me, this worked: `[<img src="https://i.imgur.com/qNuuNEP.gif" title="Click to enlarge.">](https://i.imgur.com/qNuuNEP.gif)`. I uploaded directly to `imgur.com`.