# Are we now stuck with the gif, post, and thread tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Recently [this question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/599) was migrated from the main site.

The OP created the [gif](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gif), [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post), and [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread) tags when originally posting the question, which were then removed by the migration process.

The tags still exist, and are in the prompt:

[image: tags]

Since there is no way to edit the original post on the main site and remove the tags, are we now stuck with the [gif](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gif), [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post), and [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread) tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've deleted the original question from the main site (something that the community and moderators could also have done).

The post would have gotten deleted automatically anyway, but this just speeds things along.

Since there are no existing posts with these tags on the site (as can be seen on their respective tag pages), the daily automated cleanup job will remove these tags.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find the original post, but always ended up on meta.. How does one go about finding originals of migrated posts (to cast delete votes etc.)?

Comment: The migration target will have a notification box with a link to the original - `"migrated from <site> <date time>"`. Where `<site>` is a link to the original. See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C31bE.png).

Comment: @gandalf3 I was thinking about this same thing, read about it and was prepared to wait the 30 days for the system to delete the question. Thank you both.

Comment: Another option is simply to retag the original with some tags that you do want to keep on the sites... @gandalf3