# How to record steps in Blender

Tags: discussion

Sometimes here people post amazing gifs that show their workflow. 
These are really compact sequences, often with keyboard shortcuts displayed.
How does one do that? And what additional software is needed?

Comment: This should have been posted on Meta.

Comment: Related: [placing .gifs in text](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/522/2217), [How can I insert videos into my Q&A?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/637/2217), and [How to post gifs on this site?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/404/2217)

Comment: Regarding to capturing keys pressed - what program was used e.g. [in this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/how-to-draw-grease-pencil-on-a-surface-blender-2-75/35311#35311). I have found [related page](http://www.lassanamagassa.com/2014/09/7-apps-that-display-real-time-keystrokes-on-a-windows-pc-screen/), but it seems there isn't that program included. Others still work but are a little bit less intuitive (and some of them less new)

Comment: @MrZak it looks to me like that was made with [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap) (I use that too)

Comment: @David, that's strange. I use it too and the only options I've found are those appearing once Record button is pressed. I didn't see anything related in [that window](http://i.imgur.com/lDBTgHf.jpg)

Comment: @David, found. Those are captured by Screencast Key Status Tool as in the answer mentioned. It's maybe deprecated but imo the best I've seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only post animated gifs, smaller than 2MB.
Read: [How to post gifs on this site?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site)

To create those you need some kind of screen capture software like [LiceCap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) or [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) (those work for windows, or linux using wine).

To make the keystrokes visible you can use the now deprecated [Screencast Key Status Tool](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool) or other external software.

Comment: But how come that these videos are so compact? I don't see any mouse movements and no gaps.

Comment: It all depends on the app used to capture, some have the option to show the cursor, others don't.  Size depends on the length, size, number of colors and optimization. To deal with gifs hat are larger than 2MB (or other kinds of video) you need to post them on an external site and add the link to the question.

Comment: Technically both gifcam and licecap support capturing the cursor, however neither do this very well when used through wine on linux. So my gifs don't have cursors :/