# What should the "MathJax help" link (on the Editing Help page) point to?

Tags: discussion, help-center, hyperlinks, mathjax

[MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is a JavaScript library that displays mathematical notation in web browsers, using MathML, LaTeX, to display "pretty" math notation, useful when describing complex constraints, drivers, shaders, among others, like the example below.

Typing `$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$` produces

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$

It was recently pointed out by a community manager over chat that on sites where [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is enabled, the [Markdown editing help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) page includes a link to a MathJax formatting help guide.

By default, this link points to the URL https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/, which is an external site.

This link can apparently be customized, and on a few sites it points to a dedicated meta post about it; on others, to the Mathematics Meta post "[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)".

**Since our site has MathJax enabled, where should our help page link point to?**

Ideally this would point to our own meta post about it, but other suggestions are welcome.

Anyone is free to post their own suggestions, one per answer. Please vote on the answers below that you think serve our community best, downvote the ones that do a disservice. The answer with most votes will be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

It should point to the existing Mathematics Meta quick reference which is comprehensive and well written.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'd vote for this one, since typing a new guide is a lot of work, and blatantly copy pasting that one here and maintaining it seems unnecessary plagiarism.

Comment: I agree, this post already covers everything that you would need to know. There is nothing special about MathJax's usage on Blender's Stack Exchange, so I do not see any benefit for a custom reference/guideline post on our Meta.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thansk for the feedback. If we go with this, maybe we then also link to it from our meta markup guidelines: [Guidelines on the usage of StackExchange Markup and style](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to our own MathJax webpage, as [suggested by Duarte](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2963/69907), you are welcome to link at the end of the new guide to the two MathJax webpages that I am the author of:

https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/51 and https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/278

Using those links gives me credit for referring people, but you are welcome to vote and edit too. Those sites contain additions specific to the respective site, and unique compared to what is offered at the [Mathematics MathJax FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/510296).

Comment: Are there some cool perks for referring people? I always treated it just as convenient link shorteners :D.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, Yes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/publicity-badges/info, for example:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist

Answer (score 1):

It should point to our existing [Markup Guideline](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style) meta post, where a new answer specific to Mathjax would be posted.

This would require typing a dedicated guide as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

A new post on our meta should be written specifically dedicated to Mathjax markup alone.

Comment: [Mathematics Meta Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/43517) is absolutely amazing, however I only now learned about the [Harvard](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) alternative, and I think its academic approach of explaining how it works is important as well. This answer allows to create a list of resources, rather than choosing one. It also allows to pick BSE specific snippets as examples of the usage. Rather than further extending already bloated Markup Guideline, it could link to it and be linked from it.

Comment: That is a fair point. Would you be willing to provide or help write such a post as an answer?

Comment: Sure, though I'm not an expert on Mathjax. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the current link to https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/