# How do I ask a question that is hard to describe?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm new to Blender and I ran into a problem, I'm not sure of how to accurately explain my problem. How can I best explain/show the community the issue I'm having to get some help?

Comment: Your new to blender? Wow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Blender is a *visual* application, words will go a far way but a picture is worth a thousand words or so the saying goes.

The recommended current workflow is to either use as many images as needed to illustrate the issue or to submit the problematic file for inspection.

## Solution 1

A *well worded* question can trump all, provided you describe the steps that are necessary to reproduce your problem or show what you have achieved and where you want to go. The editing text area uses markdown and supports basic html editing so you can ***highlight*** your points etc, list any steps and bring your point across as best as you can. If you aren't sure what feature X is or how to explain what a modifier or operation does, just mention that — the chances of someone knowing are high.

---

## Solution 2

**Upload image(s) showing the problem(s)**. See [How can I optimize images and screenshots that I embed in my post?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/12) for more information regarding this and how you could fit several images neatly in your question without making your post extra long.

At the end of the day, either of these solutions would be good, the ideal solution being a combination of 1 and 2 (for more complex questions). Definitely better than a string of vague words thrown together.

---

## Solution 3

**Record a small video/gif of the problem** and upload that. Tools you can use are [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) or [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) (preferred), these run natively on Windows but can also be executed on linux under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). If the resulting gif exceeds 2MB in size you can upload it to [gfycat](https://gfycat.com/) and then add the link in your post. Otherwise you can use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) directly from StackExchange as you would with any other image. See [How to post gifs on this site?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/599) for more detail.

If you are more advanced or have the software readily on hand, Camtasia, CamStudio (free), Open Broadcaster Software (free), Bandicam (free but with watermark), Fraps (free) and recordmydesktop, simplescreenrecorder on linux etc are good for recording your session.

---

## Solution 4

**Share your file** - people might be working on projects and not want to share their project files, that's fine, but if that's the case, try to recreate the specific problem in another file or edit that scene to isolate the problem. This is usually the fastest way to get help especially if your problem is a localized one, a seasoned Blender user can usually immediately spot whatever the problem is.

Comment: Good reference to point new users to.

Comment: I totally agree with the solutions you propose. If people intend to use a 3D creation software, they should be able to make some screen captures and annotate them ;) In the list of utilities, I would add QuickTime Player that comes gratis with every Mac. It has screen recording functionalities that often people ignore.

Comment: also a site called [ezgif](http://ezgif.com/)  allows for on-line optimization of GIFs, very handy to get the sizes down sometimes.

Comment: I didn't put them in levels but I agree it could be read incrementally.