# A question form

Tags: feature-request

Maybe a question form, with the Image Link field required, should be introduced to the site? It must be wearisome to ask for screenshots all the time. I noticed these requests are pretty frequent here.

Comment: It is [already changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links?cb=1) which made uploading images from external resources [even harder than it was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317578/cant-upload-image-from-url-anymore) so maybe doing this easier is not what is meant to be done

Answer (score 2):

On a site like ours where we have such a broad range of questions. I've always been against any kind of question template. The reason being that no matter how you craft a template you will have good questions that do not fit the prebuilt question pattern.

If we go and "require" screen shots what would happen to all the questions where images are not really needed?

- [What is the NLA Editor used for?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64904/2217)
- [Can Blender render pngs with the background transparent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/2217)
- [Is there a way to have one material for cycles and the BI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6446/2217)
- [What's the quickest, easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43/2217)
- [Controlling the "strength" of cycles' Bump node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31489/2217)
- [Precisely move the 3D cursor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/2217)
- [What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/2217)
- [How move object between scenes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14455/2217)

and on and on.

Not every question needs a picture.

---

The reason asking for screen shots is so common, is because we have a lot of "I have a problem with blender, can you fix it?" and we need a lot more detail to answer.
If everybody asking such questions took the time to narrow down their problem so they could ask a specific question, we'd be in a whole different boat. Lots of things would be different, and better. But as it stands we get a deluge of low quality, and in many cases plain unanswerable questions.

*So instead of forcing everybody to include a picture, why not just try to get people to write better questions?*

Comment: For some time I wanted to have kind of cast-vote on the question but instead of closing there would be crafted comment added with "add images, see how etc". This however doesn't really fit with site model, just a thought about easier handling with lots of "pls add images" comments

Comment: @MrZak believe it or not that is very similar to [an excellent idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/3220986) from one of the CMs I saw on the meta. Lets *hope* SE management lets something like this happen.

Comment: If so, questions could be read before they`re published. In case of bad quality a message like"Question rejected. Be more specific." may be sent.

Comment: I go over some tips here from wayback -- https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe/609#609