# Place to store frequently used markdown

Tags: discussion

As a new user (1 month) I need to learn about how to do this or that. A good exemple is [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-can-i-optimize-images-and-screenshots-that-i-embed-in-my-post). As I don't remember the exact syntax, I need to open the link every time i'm posting an image.

**I'd like to have a "box" where I can put links, commands or texts that I can use when needed and edit when i want to add/remove/change something.**

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like a good use for a local text file to me..

Comment: what i'm doing, but switching from notepad to browser is tedious. Getting the good tool where you need it seems better to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off there is a helpful box to the right of the input on the ask a question page. It holds some of the most conman markdown syntax. If you click the link in the box called [formatting help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help) it will take you to a much more comprehensive list of the mark down syntax.
[image: screen shot of the ask a question page]

If you have just a few conmanly used lines you want to save I don't think there is any problem with putting them in your user profile, ([I do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2217/david)).

You could use a external editor to write your question and answers (but for most question and answers it is overboard).

There are many good options available as online apps and as downloads.

- [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/editor) (my favorite of the web based)
- [dillinger](http://dillinger.io/)
- [markable](http://markable.in/editor/)
- [markdown-editor](http://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/)
- [brackets](http://brackets.io/) with the [markdown addon](https://github.com/gruehle/MarkdownPreview)

If you just want to have a place to keep notes on the question page try one of these browser addons.
FireFox [floatnotes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/floatnotes/), [internote](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-uS/firefox/addon/internote/)
chrome [Note Anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/note-anywhere/bohahkiiknkelflnjjlipnaeapefmjbh?hl=en) (I have not used any of the browser extensions)

Comment: really interesting links, thanks. I just thought it would be a good BSE improvement, especially for new users. Formatting is an example, rules, things to check later, ideas, to-do or anything relative to BSE navigation or use to remember. BSE (and SE) is so dense!